# Proving that two operators are finite-rank

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Verify whether the following operators $L^2[a, b] \to L^2[a, b]$ are finite-rank operators.
>
> a) $Kf(t) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \phi_j(t)\int_a^b \psi_j(s) f(s)\,\mathrm ds$, where $\phi_j, \psi_j \in L^2[a, b]$;
>   b) $Mf(t) = \int_a^t \phi(s)\,\mathrm ds$, where $\phi \in L^2[a, b]$.

For the first one we have that
$$Kf(t) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \alpha_j \phi_j(t),\qquad \alpha_j \in \mathbb F$$
and therefore $\operatorname{Im} K \subset \operatorname{span}\{\phi_j\}_{j = 1}^n$, giving $$\dim\operatorname{Im}K < n$$ and so the first one is finite-rank.

I have no idea how to approach the second one though, any hints?

Comment: There seems to be something msising in the second one; $f$ doesn't appear in the right hand side of the expression.

Comment: @Servaes I found that suspicious as well, but that's how the exercise is written. Could it be $\int_a^t \phi(s)f(s)\,\mathrm ds$?

Comment: It could be. On the other hand $\int_a^t\phi(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$ can also be a perfectly fine function, though the operator $M$ would not be linear unless $\phi=0$. This would suggest it should be $\int_a^t\phi(s)f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$, but you should check with whomever gave you the exercise.